# Writing textlist in codesys

Tags: codesys

How should I write a text list in CODESYS dynamically at runtime ?

I am using the text list as a source to display in a combo box (drop down list box)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are u solved problem? I'm using string and inserting "," hook between elements... Its monitor detects it as new index. But max string value is 255. There is problem. Any sugestion?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to get the text list factory using the `ComponentManager` to create an instance:

```
    const Guid TextListFactoryGuid = new Guid("{7a60005b-e690-45b3-8aca-cd15950a3e73}");
    var textListFactory = (IObjectFactory)ComponentManager.Singleton.CreateInstance(TextListFactoryGuid);
```

Then, create an instance of the test list object itself:

```
    var textListObject = (ITextListObject)textListFactory.Create();
```

The text list object will need to be added to the object manager:

```
    SystemInstances.ObjectManager.AddObject(
            SystemInstances.Engine.Projects.PrimaryProject.Handle,
            parentGuid,
            Guid.NewGuid(),
            textListObject,
            textListName,
            -1);
```

Finally, now that you have the `ITextListObject`, you can add strings to it an `id` and an `item`:

```
    textListObject.AddEmptyRow();
    var textListElement = textListObject.GetTextListRowAt(textListObject.Count - 1);
    textListElement.ID = id;
    textListElement.Default = item;
```

Hope that's what you're after